# Adding HTML tags around text in Java

Tags: java, android, string, replace, string-parsing

Get a string from server `"Hello, my e-mail email@email.com write here please"`. 
Need to surround email with HTML tags and make such string

```
"Hello, my e-mail <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a> write here please"
```

How can I make it in Java?
I need to make it because I need to paste formatted string in  `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml())`

Comment: You can use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `android:autoLink="email"`
 on your TextView xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a `Matcher` to find all of your emails inside a `String` and then `replaceAll` to edit your `String` like this:

```
yourString = getHtmlString(yourString);

private String getHtmlString(String s) {
    List<String> emails = getEmailsFromString(s);

    if (emails.size() < 1) {
        return s;
    }

    String result = s;

    for (String email : emails) {
        String toReplace = "<a href=\"" + email + "\">email@email.com</a>";
        result.replaceAll(email, toReplace);
    }

    return result;
}

private List<String> getEmailsFromString(String s) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        emails.add(m.group());
    }

    return emails;
}
```